# "get" method in class syntax returning undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm very new to js, so please be patient with me. I'm trying to complete an exercise from edabit about classes and objects.

The exercise is detailed below:

Book Shelf
Create a Book constructor that has two properties :

Title
Author
and two methods:

A getter for title that returns: "Title: " + the instance title.
A getter for the author that returns: "Author: " + the instance author.
and instantiate this constructor by creating 3 new books:

Pride and Prejudice - Jane Austen (PP)
Hamlet - William Shakespeare (H)
War and Peace - Leo Tolstoy (WP)
Name the new object instances PP, H, and WP, respectively.

For instance, if I instantiated the following book using this Book constructor function:

Harry Potter - J.K. Rowling (HP)
I would get the following properties and methods:

Examples
HP.title ➞ "Harry Potter"

HP.author ➞ "J.K. Rowling"

HP.getTitle() ➞ "Title: Harry Potter"

HP.getAuthor() ➞ "Author: J.K. Rowling"

so, here is my code so far:

```js
function makeBook() {
  "use strict";
  class Book {
    constructor(title, author) {
      this.title = title;
      this.author = author;
    }
    get Title() {
      return "Title: " + this.Title;
    }
    set Title(newTitle) {
      this.title = newTitle;
    }
    get Author() {
      return "Author: " + this.Author;
    }
    set Author(newAuthor) {
      this.author = newAuthor;
    }
  }
  return Book;
}

var Book = makeBook();

var pp = new Book("Pride and Prejudice", "Jane Austin");

var h = new Book("Hamlet", "William Shakespear");

var wp = new Book("War and Peace", "Leo Tolstoy");

console.log(wp.title); // returns "war and peace"

wp.title = "Peace And War"

console.log(wp.title) // returns "peace and war"

console.log(wp.getTitle) // returns undefined

console.log(wp.getAuthor) // returns undefined
```

I don't understand why the get methods are returning undefined. Any help is greatly appreciated.  thank you!

Comment: You haven't defined a `getTitle` method, nor a `getAuthor` method, thus `undefined`

Comment: Check the documentation for getter and setter: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get. You don't actually generate those names in the object.

Answer (score 0):

There's two issues:

- getters/setters are not called directly
- Self-referencing getters

**getters/setters are not called directly**

Getters are not called like methods, so they won't be called like `wp.getTitle()`. Instead, they are called when *accessing* the variable. So just doing `wp.Title` is enough to call the getter.

Similarly, the setter is called when assigning a value like so:

```
wp.Title = "Stephen King"
```

**Self-referencing getters**

After the above issue is fixed, you might have another issue. `this.title` and `this.author` are the properties that hold the values, according to your `constructor`. When the respective getter for the `Title` and `Author` (note the uppercase here) are called, they are effectively calling themselves and will cause a max call stack error.

There's no such thing as private, class properties so a lot of people like to prefix variables that are intended to be private with an underscore. This might help keep the confusing down when using similarly named getters, setters, and properties.

```js
    function makeBook() {
      "use strict";
      class Book {
        constructor(title, author) {
          this.title = title;
          this.author = author;
        }
        get Title() {
          // lowercase version to ref the property
          return "Title: " + this.title;
        }
        set Title(newTitle) {
          this.title = newTitle;
        }
        get Author() {
          // lowercase version to ref the property
          return "Author: " + this.author;
        }
        set Author(newAuthor) {
          this.author = newAuthor;
        }
      }
      return Book;
    }

    var Book = makeBook();

    var pp = new Book("Pride and Prejudice", "Jane Austin");

    var h = new Book("Hamlet", "William Shakespear");

    var wp = new Book("War and Peace", "Leo Tolstoy");

    console.log(wp.title); // returns "war and peace"

    wp.title = "Peace And War"

    console.log(wp.title) // returns "peace and war"

    // remove the "get" prefix
    console.log(wp.Title)

    // remove the "get" prefix
    console.log(wp.Author)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `makeBook()` function at all, just declare the class.

Your getters are trying to access themselves not the attribute so they are endlessly recusing and "Stack Overflowing". This.title should be lowercase for example

```
get Title() {
  return "Title: " + this.title;
}
```

So I think you want

```
class Book {
  constructor(title, author) {
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
  }
  get Title() {
    return "Title: " + this.title;
  }
  set Title(newTitle) {
    this.title = newTitle;
  }
  get Author() {
    return "Author: " + this.author;
  }
  set Author(newAuthor) {
    this.author = newAuthor;
  }
}

var pp = new Book("Pride and Prejudice", "Jane Austin");

var h = new Book("Hamlet", "William Shakespear");

var wp = new Book("War and Peace", "Leo Tolstoy");
```